# Java - UDP Multithreaded Server

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

How do you implement a Thread that handles client requests on the server using UDP. I have read somewhere you can use ThreadPoolExecutor, is using this method ok. Becuase there isnt much articles on the web that give you any examples of using Multithreaded UDP applications.
So my question is should i use ThreadPoolExecutor?
Does someone have an example of how to implement A Multithreaded UDP Server/ Client application?

This is simple to do using TCP so i have used TCP Multithreading, just wanted to grasp how UDP works this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is Executors is not at all an issue here. It doesnot matter if you use a ThreadPoolExecutor or use manual threads to do it. ThreadPoolExecutor or any other ExecutorService for that matter is just a service to manage threads and work accordingly. It has got nothing do with what your RUnnable's or Callable's are.

In your program you will only be giving Runnables or Callables to a executor. ExecutorService doesn't care of what is inside the runnable because its his job to execute them. So the way of using ExecutorService for TCP server or UDP server doesn't change as far as dealing with ThreadPoolExecutor. Just modify the RUnnable to be sent and all done :)

Answer (score 0):

The main trick with UDP is that it is unreliable.  You have to implement your own detection/handling of lost packets.

Once you have requests, you can use an Executors.newXxxxxx() just the same as TCP.

Comment: Hi peter, i dont really mind if packets are lost. Could i still use the ThreadPoolExector?

Comment: Executors is a helper class for ThreadPoolExecutor. You can use either but I would use Executors if you can.